# Use ADS1115 to measure voltage

Tags: adc

I would like to measure the voltage of each element of a battery pack made of 18650 cells.

I use an [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf) to get the voltage.  My problem that when I measure an element each time everything is ok but as soon as I try to measure several elements at the same time on the battery the voltage values ​​are completely wrong.

[image]

I am in differential mode

I would like to measure A0 - A1; A2 - A3 but I can't if both 18650 cells are connected together.

Comment: Two 18650s in series is *way* outside of the analog input voltage range of the ADS1115; you've almost certainly destroyed it just by wiring up this circuit.

Comment: use single ended readings, and send them through a voltage divider to scale down to the max v for the inputs.

Answer (score 4):

From the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf):

[image]

You can see by looking at the absolute maximum allowed analog input voltage, you are exceeding the range of the device.  Two of those cells in series is outside that range, and you have likely damaged the device.

Looking just a bit further down at the recommended range:

[image]

You shouldn't be going more than 6.144 V across the inputs.  Two 18650 in series is ~7.4 V nominal, but can be as high as 8.4 V!

Also note that you should not be going outside the supply voltage range (which you haven't specified).

Comment: Thx for your answer but i am in differential mode so Vin = V(AINP) - V(AINN) should be correct due to the multiplexer wich is placed so just after the inputs ? because A0 - A1 < 6.144V and A2 - A3 < 6.144V ?

Comment: BTW, The absolute maximum rating applies to the pins alone. Even if their voltages are subtracted internally to work in differential mode. Thus you are effectively out of range.

Comment: ok thanks , but the multiplexer select the voltage send to the real ADC ??? PAGE 15 of datasheet so there is no reason to substracted them internally

Comment: The limits on the analog inputs have nothing to do with after the multiplexer.  Those are hard limits on the input itself.  The "absolute input voltage" is being exceeded.  If the batteries are in series, you cannot get around that fact.